# Exception Handler for DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to give an error message for datetime. I mean, if datetime does not contains all months in table, it should be give an warning.How can I do this?

For ex: DateTime: `2017/01/01T00:00:00`, `2017/02/01T00:00:00`,  ... `2017/12/01T00:00:00`, in table and I want to control

if `2017/01/01T00:00:00`, `2017/02/01T00:00:00`,  ... `2017/12/01T00:00:00`, does not contains give an error.

I want to control

```
if(datetime != "1.01.2017 00:00:00" && datetime != "1.02.2017 00:00:00" && datetime != "1.03.2017 00:00:00" && datetime != "1.04.2017 00:00:00" && datetime != "1.05.2017 00:00:00" && datetime != "1.06.2017 00:00:00" && datetime != "1.07.2017 00:00:00" && datetime != "1.08.2017 00:00:00" && datetime != "1.09.2017 00:00:00" && datetime != "1.10.2017 00:00:00" && datetime != "1.11.2017 00:00:00" && datetime != "1.12.2017 00:00:00")
{

    throw new Error("Please enter all months");

}
```

But how can I write more efficient code?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please provide sample code.

Comment: @ dman2306 If datetime != 1.01.2017 00:00:00 && datetime != 1.02.2017 00:00:00..so on give an error

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: "if datetime does not contains all months in table" - What???

Comment: @ Usman  I dont know how to write this code.I mean instead of If datetime != 1.01.2017 00:00:00 && datetime != 1.02.2017 00:00:00.What can I write more shorter code?

Comment: @ Enigmativity  Is it not clear? Ok, I want to control datetime != 1.01.2017 && 1.02.2017 && 1.03.2017 && 1.04.2017 && 1.05.2017 throw an exception.But how can I write more efficient code?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `Enumerable.Range(0, 12).All(n => new DateTime(2017, 1, 1).AddMonths(n) != datetime);`

Comment: @ Enigmativity Yes,and give an error like that "Please enter this months"..sth like that

Comment: @harry - You need to show us your code. You're asking us to code for you. Show us your code and tell us where you're stuck. Then we can help. Otherwise, what I wrote two comments ago should be sufficient to answer this question.

Comment: @ Enigmativity I editted my question

Comment: you mean if datatime is not in 2017 it will give error?

Comment: @ Usman yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
   DateTime time =  Convert.ToDateTime("2016/01/01T00:00:00");

    if (time.Year != 2017)
    {
            throw  new Exception("not in 2017");
    }
```

this will check the year if its `2017` it will pass else it will `throw exception`

**Edit**

to count months in string you can do it like this

```
 int total =0;
            var strlist = new [] { "2017 / 01 / 01T00:00:00", "2017 / 02 / 01T00: 00:00" };
            foreach (var date in strlist)
            {
                var datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
                if (datetime.Year == 2017)
                {
                    total++;
                }
            }
            if (total <12)
            {
                throw new Exception("Please enter all months");
            }
```

Comment: but it should be control months.I editted my quesiton

Comment: can you show the value of datetime in your question? will it be array of string?

Comment: I showed it. 1.01.2017, 1.02,2017,1.03.2017,1.04.2017 should be controlled

Comment: i dont understand you want count to be 12 of months

Comment: Yes, but which month is missing what sould I know in exception

Comment: will the data be sorted?

Comment: @Usman - You really shouldn't suggest throwing a vanilla `Exception` like that. It's always best to create subclass in this case.